# Mongodb C# Update element in an multiple array with multiple values

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I want to update the single document in collection with the guid as filter and update value is cityType. Every guid has different citytype here i have used 3 types it may be more.
So please give a right implementation using c# code.

Models:

```
public class Country
    {
        [BsonId]
        public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
        public int CountryId {get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<States> States { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class States
    {
        public Guid Guid { get; set; }
        public CityType CityType { get; set; }
    }
    
    Enum CityType
    {
      Unknown = 0,
      Rural = 1,
      Urban = 2
    }
```

Existing Collection:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("6903ea4d2df0c5659334e763"),
    "CountryId": 200,
    "States": [
      {
        "Guid": "AFCC4BE7-7585-5E46-A639-52F0537895D8",
        "CityType": 0,
      },
      {
        "Guid": "208FB603-08C7-46D9-B0C0-7AF4F691A96D",
        "CityType": 0,
      }
    }
```

Input:

```
List<States>()
    {
        new States()
        {
           Guid = "AFCC4BE7-7585-5E46-A639-52F0537895D8",
           CityType = CityType.Rural
        },
        new States()
        {
           Guid = "208FB603-08C7-46D9-B0C0-7AF4F691A96D",
           CityType = CityType.Urban
        }
    }
```

Expected:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("6903ea4d2df0c5659334e763"),
    "CountryId": 200,
    "States": [
      {
        "Guid": "AFCC4BE7-7585-5E46-A639-52F0537895D8",
        "CityType": 1,
      },
      {
        "Guid": "208FB603-08C7-46D9-B0C0-7AF4F691A96D",
        "CityType": 2,
      }
    }
```

This is the method I have tried:

```
public async Task<bool> UpdateType(int countryId, IEnumerable<States> states)
      {
         var collection = connectionFactory.GetCollection<Country>(collectionName);

         var cityTypes = states.Select(x => x.CityType);
         var filter = Builders<Country>.Filter.Empty;
         var update = Builders<Country>.Update.Set("States.$[edit].CityType", cityTypes);

         var arrayFilters = new List<ArrayFilterDefinition>();

         foreach (var state in states)
         {
            ArrayFilterDefinition<Country> optionsFilter = new BsonDocument("state.Guid", new BsonDocument("$eq", state.Guid));
            arrayFilters.Add(optionsFilter);
         }

         var updateOptions = new UpdateOptions { ArrayFilters = arrayFilters };

         var result = await collection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update, updateOptions);
         return result;
      }
```

hope all details I have added here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can get some help from [here](https://kevsoft.net/2020/03/23/updating-arrays-in-mongodb-with-csharp.html)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to loop through it:

Let's say you have a Class1 like this:

```
class Question : AuditableEntity {
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public List<string> Tags { get; set; } = new List<string>();
```

so you just say:

```
await collection.UpdateOneAsync(
            someFilter,
            Builders<Class1>.Update
                .Set(f => f.Text, request.Question.Text)
                .Set(f => f.Tags, request.Question.Tags));
```